# get r"D:\test.txt" or "D:\\test.txt" from glob.glob("D\\*.txt")

Tags: python

I want to get `r"D:\test.txt"` or `"D:\\test.txt"` from `glob.glob` list.

I tried as follows.

```
files = glob.glob("D\\*.txt")
for fi in files:
  print (fi)
```

It just gives, `"D\test.txt"`.

How to make it `r"D:\test.txt"` or `"D:\\test.txt"`

- `fi` is given condition.
- I need to get it as string (`r"D:\test.txt"` or `"D:\\test.txt"`).

  - I also tried as `print (str(fi).replace("\", "\\"))` but python does not allow writing this code.
- I am using windows.

Comment: What you want is the representation of the string, so `print(repr(fi))` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have fi as `"D:\test.txt"` if that is a string you replace function to convert \ into \

`fi = fi.replace("\\","\\\\")`

First \ is for escape second \ is for search in the fi string
in the four \, 2 for escape and 2 for your string.